# Evitar que a fórmula PROCV retorne um erro

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula, procv

Existe alguma configuração no Excel ou algum modo de fazer com que a fórmula PROCV, quando não encontra o valor buscado, retorne vazio ("") ou 0 em vez do erro "#N/A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso existe a fórmula `SEERRO`. Nela vc pode configurar uma condição caso vc obtenha algum erro. O primeiro argumento é onde vc escreve a fórmula que eventualemnte pode gerar um erro, e no segundo argumento vc declara o que acontece se ocorrer um erro no primeiro argumento. Caso não retorne em erro, a fórmula traz o resultado do primeiro argumento.

```
=SEERRO( PROCV() ; "")

=SEERRO( PROCV( Argumento procurado ; Tabela de procura ; índice da coluna a retornar o valor ; FALSO/VERDADEIRO ) ; resultado caso PROCV retorne em erro )
```

Há milhares de páginas na internet sobre essa fórmula. Ela é considerada básica.

Comment: Caraaaaaacas! Me senti muito noob agora! Procurei no google essa fórmula e tem muito conteúdo mesmo para essa coisa!

Comment: ...e resolveu meu problema! Era disso mesmo que eu precisava!